# Checking for autocorrelation

Tags: generalized-linear-model, autocorrelation, residuals, acf-pacf

I would like to check my GLM model for autocorrelation - I am wondering for Poisson, Negative Binomial and Binomial GLMs whether to use the deviance residuals or the Pearson residuals?
This is how I am trying to check my model for autocorrelation, where B1 is the name of my model (in this case a binomial GLM with a 0 or 1 Presence/Absence response variable)

residB1 <- resid(B1, type="pearson")

acf(residB2)

If I use that method, there does not appear to be too much autocorrelation. However, I get a significantly different graph if I use:

residB2<-resid(B1)

acf(residB1)

(In this case not specific the type="pearson").
Which method is correct?

Are there any other ways I could check for autocorrelation?

Thanks!

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/index.html has autocorrelation tests for glms